# different data types in a matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have a matrix like this:

```
[[-0.96092685  1.16253848]
 [ 1.49414781  0.265738  ]
 [ 0.02689231 -1.09912591]
 ...
 [ 0.16677277  1.43807138]
 [-0.36808792 -0.03435113]
 [-0.3693595   0.44464701]]
```

and another matrix like this:

```
[-1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 ...  1 -1  1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1  1  1 -1  1
 -1  1 -1  1  1 -1  1  1  1 -1  1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1]
```

now i want top put the last matrix as a column in the first matrix and I have done:

```
y=yL.reshape(len(yL),1)
data=np.concatenate((XL,y),axis=1)
```

but the result is:

```
[[-0.96092685  1.16253848 -1.        ]
 [ 1.49414781  0.265738    1.        ]
 [ 0.02689231 -1.09912591 -1.        ]
 ...
 [ 0.16677277  1.43807138 -1.        ]
 [-0.36808792 -0.03435113 -1.        ]
 [-0.3693595   0.44464701 -1.        ]]
```

but i want the 1 and -1 to be int not float, how can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. In numpy, all the elements of a `np.array` have to share the same datatype. If you want *columns* having different datatypes, you should use Pandas.

Comment: thanks, but if I write my matrix in this way I can have different data typer:

dataset = [[2.7810836,2.550537003,0],
    [1.465489372,2.362125076,0],
    [3.396561688,4.400293529,0],
    [1.38807019,1.850220317,0],
    [3.06407232,3.005305973,0],
    [7.627531214,2.759262235,1],
    [5.332441248,2.088626775,1],
    [6.922596716,1.77106367,1],
    [8.675418651,-0.242068655,1],
    [7.673756466,3.508563011,1]]

Comment: @MementoMori: this is not a numpy array but a plain Python list. They are quite different animals!